# how to mask a column data in oracle

Tags: oracle

newbie - trying to mask a column's data in oracle which consists of nearly 70 million records.Need to update all records in table.
Tried to update using this statement which ran beyond 2 hours.
Have not leanred to work in pl/sql yet, any other ways to update?

```
select * from <table> regexp_replace(A,'[A-Za-z]','X') where A is not null;
update <table> set A=(regexp_replace(A,'[A-Za-z]','X')) where A is not null;
```

Comment: when you say "masK" you truely want to update the data and replace the existing value with the regex_replace value?  basically all XXXXX when alphabetic.  this seems like a bad idea to me.  or are you wanting the data returned to be masked when selected? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295085/data-masking-in-oracle-sql-select-statement

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a lot of rows, you can't expect such an update to be done *instantly*. On the other hand, what's the purpose of doing that? Who are you hiding that information from? You do know that - once `update` is done and you `commit`, you'll have problems in returning original data back (if needed)?

Anyway: regular expressions are *beautiful* but - people say - behave worse than some other "standard" functions on large data sets (such as yours). Did you try `translate`?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Littlefoot Bigfoot 23' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '[A-Za-z]', 'X') you,
  4    translate(col, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  5                   'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') me
  6  from test;

YOU                   ME
--------------------- ---------------------
XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX 23 XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX 23

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your update is serialized. If your table has no triggers or foreign keys, you should be able to enable parallel dml and update it with the power of PX. Assuming you have the CPU cores:

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
UPDATE /*+ PARALLEL(mytable,16) */ mytable SET . . . ;
COMMIT;
```

However if you have a trigger or FK, it won't go parallel. Those might also be adding extra work if the trigger fires on update or the FK is on the column you are updating, so be sure to check these possibilities. Disabling the trigger or FK in this case might be worth it. Also if your table is compressed this update will chain the rows badly... uncompress the table, do the update, then recompress if that's the case. But in all probability, you just need some parallelism.